# Can Host header passed to a Heroku application be trusted?

Tags: heroku

I'm developing Heroku application that will be accessible via several domains. I need to distinguish to which particular domain a request is related. This is needed for example to construct absolute URLs of resources returned in the `Location` header.

Can I trust the `Host` header that arrives in the request to a Heroku application to always point to a domain that is associated with the application (either default `xyz.herokuapp.com` domain or one of domains added with `heroku domains:add` command)?

I know that this header can be set by a user to whatever value, but Heroku front end servers need to do some kind of filtering to dispatch requests to a correct application. Is this filtering bullet proof enough to trust the `Host` header?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the request reached your application then the Host header will be one configured for your app.

If the Host header was not one of yours the Heroku servers would have sent the request elsewhere.

You can prove this on the command line by sending a wrong host.
for example:

`$ curl "http://ismy.herokuapp.com" -H "Host: notmy.herokuapp.com"`

So, the answer to your question is yes. I'd trust it.

Comment: This sounds promising, but I worry about tricky cases. Currently I can think of two: 1. Persistent HTTP connection, where the first request has a correct Host, but subsequent requests set it to some different, incorrect value. Will Heroku drop the subsequent requests over the same TCP connection? 2. SSL connection for a custom domain. Because SSL (without SNI extension) requires dedicated IP address, Heroku could route HTTPS requests based only on the destination IP address, not a Host header inside.

Comment: I've done more extensive testing and found a case where a request is rooted to different application than Host header indicates, but Heroku backends are correcting the header. The tricky case is when request uses absolute URL: `telnet foo.herokuapp.com 80;` followed by `GET http://foo.herokuapp.com/path HTTP/1.1\n Host: bar.herokuapp.com\n\n` is routed to `foo.herokuapp.com` (this is inline with HTTP spec), but the Host header is overwritten by Heroku to also be `foo.herokuapp.com`